# Problem with audiences not recognizing AD Groups

Tags: user-profile-service, audience-targeting, audiences

I have a problem where my audiences are finding the correct AD groups but they are not being recognized when I assign them.  They show up with "nickname" as the alias and total members set to "0".  This started happening after I had to change passwords for the User Profile Service and recreate the synchronization connection.  I've tried running full synchronization and running the "My Site Cleanup Job" but neither of those solutions worked.  Any Ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a SharePoint Group and I put the AD Group "Revit User Group" under the SharePoint Group.  Then I assigned the SharePoint Group as the Audience and everything worked fine.